# Index creation taking forever on postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I was trying to create an index to an integer column using a btree index, but it was taking forever (more than 2 hours!).
The table has 17.514.879 lines. I didn't expect it to take that long.

After almost 2.5 hours, the connection to the database just died. When I reconnected to it, the index was there, but I don't know how good is this index.

How can I be sure the index was not messed up by the connection lost?

Comment: The the statement was most probably waiting for a lock: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring  If the index is there, it should be fine

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## How to Check Whether the Index is Fine

Connect to the database via `psql` and run `\d table_name` (where `table_name` is the name of your table). For example:

```
grn=# \d users
            Table "public.users"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers
--------+------------------------+-----------
 name   | character varying(255) |
Indexes:
    "users_name_idx" btree (name)
```

You'll see indexes listed below the table schema. If the index is corrupt it'll be marked as so.

## How to Create Indexes Without Locking the Whole Table

You can create an index in a way that doesn't lock the whole table but is *even* slower. To do so you need to add `CONCURRENTLY` to `CREATE INDEX`. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY users_name_idx ON users(name);
```

## How to Fix a Corrupt Index

If the index is corrupt you can either drop it and recreate `CONCURRENTLY` or use `REINDEX INDEX index_name`. For example:

```
REINDEX INDEX users_name_idx
```

will recreate the `users_name_idx`.

Comment: Watch out using RECREATE will recreate the index NOT CONCURRENTLY and lock your table. Use REINDEX CONCURRENTLY (since pg 12) to recreate the index concurrently